# Have WordPress with a different index file for testing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

A site I'm designing a website for was built with static HTML files. I'm converting it to WordPress but I need the old site to still function while WordPress is installed in the same directory (e.g. have `index.html` be the default one and then have WordPress be something like `indexNew.php`)

So they go to `http://domain.com/indexNew.php` to see updates to the new website until it's finished.

How would I configure that in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .htaccess with a simply rule to redirect users to index.html except you :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule $ /index.html [R=302,L]
```

Replace 123.123.123.123 by your public ip adress.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your .htaccess to set the default document order:

> Tired of having yoursite.com/index.html come up when you go to yoursite.com? Want to change it to be yoursite.com/ILikePizzaSteve.html that comes up instead? No problem!

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess6.shtml

In your case, you won't need to rename the index.php at all - this will do the trick:

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Anyone who requests yoursite.com will see the content from index.html. To see the new Wordpress content, just navigate to yoursite.com/index.php